# How to get "smime.p7s" from email and extract sender and organization name in Node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, digital-signature, smime

My task is to ensure that the email has a digital signature and to read the sender's and organization's names.

I tried to use "imap" package. This snippet reads the body content and then tries to parse the attributes

```
 msg.on('body', function(stream, info) {
      var buffer = '';
      stream.on('data', function(chunk) {
        buffer += chunk.toString('utf8');
      });
      msg.once("attributes", (attrs) => {  
          //TODO
      });
 }
```

In the body of the email if it has a digital signature I can see something like that:

```
------=_NextPart_000_0008_01D7CCA9.33F25DA0
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature;
   name="smime.p7s"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename="smime.p7s"

MIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCAMIACAQExCzAJBgUrDgMCGgUAMIAGCSqGSIb3DQEHAQAAoIIycDCCBlUw
ggQ9oAMCAQICBHYpB+MwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgZkxCzAJBgNVBAYTAkRFMQ8wDQYDVQQIDAZC
YXllcm4xETAPBgNVBAcMCE11ZW5jaGVuMRAwDgYDVQQKDAdTaWVtZW5zMREwDwYDVQQFEwhaWlpa
WlpBMTEdMBsGA1UECwwUU2llbWVucyBUcnVzdCBDZW50ZXIxIjAgBgNVBAMMGVNpZW1lbnMgUm9
...
------=_NextPart_000_0008_01D7CCA9.33F25DA0--
```

And I expect that some attachments will be in `attributes`. **But there is nothing.**

[image]

If I attach a file I will be able to see and read this file from the attribute's parameters.

How can I get the digital signature and extract the sender's and organization's names in Node.js?
Is that even possible?
If it is impossible, how can I validate the digital signature and be sure that everything is alright?